# XPath Substring

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML file that I need to transform using an XSL script.

Below is an example feed.  I need to extract the text in the `NameLabel` element, but I only need the text specifically between the first two dashes.

For example, I want the `A` in the string below:

NTX-**A**-20120131-0006

I'm not well versed in XPath, so I'm struggling to put together an expression, however I'm assuming I need to use substring-(after|before).  I'm just not sure how.

Sample XML:

```
<NewsML>
    <NewsItem>
        <Identification>
            <NameLabel>NTX-A-20120131-0006</NameLabel>
        </Identification>
    </NewsItem>
</NewsML>
```

Edit:

I am using xslt 1.0

Comment: which version of xslt? 1 or 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
substring-before(s1,s2) and substring-after(s1,s2) would work.

substring-before(substring-after(NewsML/NewsItem/Identification/NameLabel,'-'),'-')
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="NewsItem/NewsML/Identification"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Identification">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(NameLabel,'-'),'-'))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

but i couldn't test this

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, then a better expression would be:

```
fn:replace( NewsItem/NewsML/Identification, "^.*-(.)-.*$", $1)
```

But if you are stuck with XSLT 1, then go with Aepheus's answer.